# SQL result with background color

Tags: sql, sql-server, background-color

I am trying to return a count result with background color depending on the amount of existing elements in a table.

MS SQL

```
DECLARE @cc int
SET @cc = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROBLEMS)

SELECT
CASE WHEN @cc>10 THEN concat("<div style='background-color: red'>",cast (@cc as char),"</div>") 
ELSE concat("<div style='background-color: green'>",cast (@cc as char),"</div>")
END
FROM PROBLEMS
```

Any ideas how to fix my query ?

Comment: The best fix here would be to stop doing formatting in the database. Just return the data and let your application handle formatting. That is what the presentation layer is for!!

Comment: Aside from what was stated in the previous comment, what isn't working with the query?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: how to fix what with your query?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `char` without a length.

Second, you don't need variables for this.  Just run the query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 10 THEN '<div style=''background-color: red''>'
             ELSE '<div style=''background-color: green''>'
        END) + CAST(COUNT(*) as varchar(255)) + '</div>'
FROM PROBLEMS;
```

Notes:

- Single quotes are used to delimit strings in SQL, not double quotes (some other databases do support double quotes for this purpose, but that is an extension).
- For a single quote in a string, double it up `''` (not `"`).
- Always use a length for the character type.
- The concatenation operator in SQL Server is `+`, although `concat()` also works.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated!